# Linux kernel version from an ISO image

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

With the `uname` command, and it's different options, I can get kernel version installed on a machine.

Suppose if I wanted to find out the kernel version from an ISO image, by just mounting it (without installation). How can I find the complete kernel version from ISO with out installation?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the command `file`.

```
file /mnt/boot/vmlinuz-x.y.z
```

This will generate an output like this

```
/boot/vmlinuz-3.6.10-2.fc17.x86_64: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 3.6.10-2.fc17.x86_64 (mockbuild@) #1 SMP Tue Dec 11 18:07:34 UT, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x4, Normal VGA
```

Note: Ubuntu kernel = `casper/vmlinuz`